# Dropping column names that doesn't contain number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with the following column names:

```
Name, Id, xyz,..., ijk, 1, 2, 3, val1, val2,...
```

I want to drop all the columns whose name doesn't contain number and only keep `Name` and `Id`.  Is there an efficient way to do this?

The result would be:  Name, Id, 1, 2, 3, val1, val2,...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.astype(str).str.contains('\d') | df.columns.isin(['Name','Id'])]
```

Demo:

```
In [224]: df
Out[224]:
   Name  Id  xyz  ijk  1  2  3  val1  val2
0     1   2    3    4  5  6  7     8     9

In [225]: df = df.loc[:, df.columns.astype(str).str.contains('\d') | df.columns.isin(['Name','Id'])]

In [226]: df
Out[226]:
   Name  Id  1  2  3  val1  val2
0     1   2  5  6  7     8     9
```

Answer (score 3):

With `str.match` based on MaxU's answer.

```
new_columns = df.columns[df.columns.astype(str).str.match("(.*\d.*)|Id|Name")]
df[new_columns]
```

Comment: Very nice RegEx! +1

Comment: @MaxU your use of `astype` is awesome.