# Pandas dropping columns end with number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with the following column names:

Name, xyz, ijk, 1, 2, 3, val1, val2, test1, test2
I want to drop all the columns whose name end with number but I still want to keep columns that only has number.  How can this be done?

The result would be: Name, xyz, ijk, 1, 2, 3

Thanks!

Comment: Any research? What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? You should be able to _easily_ figure out how to do this from the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511457/dropping-column-names-that-doesnt-contain-number).

Comment: @pault I was think I can do df = df[df.columns[~(df.columns.str.startswith('\d')] but this would remove the 1 2 3.. as well

Comment: You're very close. I'll give you some hints: you want the opposite of `startswith()` and maybe checking the length could be helpful.

Comment: @pault I tried df.columns[~df.columns.astype(str).str.match("(.*\d.*)") & df.columns.astype(str).str.len() > 1] but I got an error saying "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Int64Index'".  I also tried endswith function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'xyz': [1, 2, 3],
        'ijk': [1, 2, 3],
        1: [1, 2, 3],
        'val1': [1, 2, 3],
        'test1': [1, 2, 3]
    }
)

df.loc[:, ~((df.columns.astype(str).str.contains('\d$')) & (df.columns.astype(str).str.len() > 1))]
#   1  ijk  xyz
#0  1    1    1
#1  2    2    2
#2  3    3    3
```

Your code in the comments produced an error because you were missing parentheses around the two boolean Series. You could have written it as:

```
df.columns[(~df.columns.astype(str).str.match("(.*\d.*)")) & (df.columns.astype(str).str.len() > 1)]
#Index([u'ijk', u'xyz'], dtype='object')
```

But this would have actually given you the wrong answer. Instead, your logic could be modified slightly to:

```
df.columns[~((df.columns.astype(str).str.match("(.*\d)")) & (df.columns.astype(str).str.len() > 1))] 
#Index([1, u'ijk', u'xyz'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

Setup -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['xyz', 'ijk', '1', '2', '3', 'val1', 'test1', 'test2'])
df

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [xyz, ijk, 1, 2, 3, val1, test1, test2]
Index: []
```

The fundamental assumption here is *all* your column names are *strings*. Let's use `filter` for this.

```
df.filter(regex='^(?:.+\D|\d+)$')

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [xyz, ijk, 1, 2, 3]
Index: []
```

*Details*
`filter` lets you pass a regex. The pattern here is -

```
^      # SOL
(?:    # non-capture group
.+\D   # anything that does not end in a digit
|      # regex OR pipe
\d+    # *only* digits
) 
$      # EOL
```

---

If not all column names are strings, then this isn't a viable solution until you convert them -

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

`filter` will now work as before.

Comment: I had considered adding in my post that you or Wen (among others) would probably come along and give a more elegant solution. It's why I wrote "Here's _one_ way..."

Comment: @pault Hey, you'll get there in time :) Here's a plus1 for your efforts too.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! The regex detail is very useful.  I have been looking for those pattern so I can implement my code easier.

Comment: @TylerNG That's what I'm here for. ;-)